# Adding a superclass and several subclasses to my JavaFX paint program

Tags: java, javafx

I've created a paint program in JavaFX. All the code as you see is in one BIG file. So I want to create a superclass called Figure to have all that things the shapes have in common. Then I want to create subclasses for each Line, Circle, Rectangle and Polygon and maybe make drawing methods with eventhandler in each of those classes, is that possible?

This is my code:

```
package tegneprogram;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CONTROLFX MUST BE ADDED IN THE PROJECT LIBRARY TO SEE THE EFFECT
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import org.controlsfx.control.PopOver;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// DESCRIPTION:
//
// A PROGRAM THAT ALLOWS THE USER TO DRAW GEOMETRIC FIGURES WITH DIFFERENT COLORS.
// YOU CAN ALSO ADD TEXT TO THE PANE. WHEN FIGURES AND TEXT IS APPLIED YOU CAN MOUSE_PRESS
// AND MOUSE_DRAG THEM INDIVIDUALLY AND MOVE EACH ONE AROUND THE PANE.
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------




public class Tegneprogram extends Application {


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// START
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GEOMETRIC FIGURES
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     Rectangle rect; 
     Line line;
     Polygon poly;
     Circle circ;
     TextField text;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// VARIABLES FOR DRAGGING FIGURES
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    double nwPosX = 0, nwPosY = 0;
    double TX = 0, TY = 0;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
// DRAWING PANE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     Pane pane;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
// COLORPICKER
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

     ColorPicker cpFill;
     ColorPicker cpLine;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// POLYGON VARIABLES, ARRAYLIST AND DOUBLE ARRAY
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int count = 0;
double x[] = new double[3];
double y[] = new double[3];
List<Double> values = new ArrayList();


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SPACE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// TOGGLE BUTTON FOR FIGURES
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ToggleButton linebtn = new ToggleButton("Line");
        ToggleButton rectbtn = new ToggleButton("Rectangel");
        ToggleButton circbtn = new ToggleButton("Circle");
        ToggleButton polybtn = new ToggleButton("Polygon");
        ToggleButton textbtn = new ToggleButton("Text");

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// LABELS FOR INFORMATION ABOUT COLOR
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Label line_color = new Label("Line Color");
        Label fill_color = new Label("Fill Color");

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // TABLE ARRAY FOR ALL THE TOGGLE BUTTONS
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ToggleButton[] FigureTool = {linebtn, rectbtn, circbtn, polybtn, textbtn};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GROUP OBJECT FOR TOGGLEBUTTONS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ToggleGroup tools = new ToggleGroup();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
// COUNTING ALL THE BUTTONS IN TABLE ARRAY AND GROUPS THEM IN A TOGGLEGROUP
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        for(ToggleButton tool : FigureTool) {
            tool.setMinWidth(90);//width on buttons
            tool.setToggleGroup(tools);
            tool.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// COLORPICKER
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         cpLine = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);
         cpFill = new ColorPicker(Color.TRANSPARENT);         


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// HBOX FOR PLACING BUTTONS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        HBox buttons = new HBox(10);
        buttons.getChildren().addAll(linebtn, rectbtn, circbtn, polybtn, textbtn);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// STYLING FOR HBOX BUTTONS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        buttons.setStyle("-fx-background: #777");
        buttons.setPrefWidth(90);


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
// VBOX FOR PLACING LINE AND COLOR BUTTONS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        VBox colors = new VBox(10);
        colors.getChildren().addAll(line_color,cpLine,fill_color, cpFill);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
// STYLING FOR VBOX COLORS BUTTONS 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        colors.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        colors.setStyle("-fx-background: #777");


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SETTING UP DRAWING PANE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_DRAGGED LINE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    EventHandler<MouseEvent> lineMousePressed = (MouseEvent e) -> {
            nwPosX  = e.getSceneX();
            nwPosY  = e.getSceneY();
            TX  = ((Line)(e.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            TY  = ((Line)(e.getSource())).getTranslateY();


            ((Line)(e.getSource())).toFront();

        };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> lineMoveDrag = (MouseEvent e) -> {

            double newSetX = e.getSceneX() - nwPosX;
            double newSetY = e.getSceneY() - nwPosY;
            double NSX = TX + newSetX;
            double NSY = TY + newSetY;


            ((Line)(e.getSource())).setTranslateX(NSX);
            ((Line)(e.getSource())).setTranslateY(NSY);
        };


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_DRAGGED RECTANGLE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    EventHandler<MouseEvent> rectMousePressed = (MouseEvent e) -> {
            nwPosX  = e.getSceneX();
            nwPosY  = e.getSceneY();
            TX  = ((Rectangle)(e.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            TY  = ((Rectangle)(e.getSource())).getTranslateY();


           ((Rectangle)(e.getSource())).toFront();
        };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> rectMoveDrag = (MouseEvent e) -> {

            double newSetX = e.getSceneX() - nwPosX;
            double newSetY = e.getSceneY() - nwPosY;
            double NSX = TX + newSetX;
            double NSY = TY + newSetY;


            ((Rectangle)(e.getSource())).setTranslateX(NSX);
            ((Rectangle)(e.getSource())).setTranslateY(NSY);
        };



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_DRAGGED CIRCLE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circlMousePressed = (MouseEvent e) -> {
            nwPosX  = e.getSceneX();
            nwPosY  = e.getSceneY();
            TX  = ((Circle)(e.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            TY  = ((Circle)(e.getSource())).getTranslateY();


            ((Circle)(e.getSource())).toFront();

        };


    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circMoveDrag = (MouseEvent e) -> {

            double NSX = e.getSceneX() - nwPosX;
            double NSY = e.getSceneY() - nwPosY;
            double newX = TX + NSX;
            double newY = TY + NSY;


            ((Circle)(e.getSource())).setTranslateX(newX);
            ((Circle)(e.getSource())).setTranslateY(newY);
        };



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_DRAGGED POLYGON
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> polyMousePressed = (MouseEvent e) -> {

            nwPosX  = e.getSceneX();
            nwPosY  = e.getSceneY();
            TX  = ((Polygon)(e.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            TY  = ((Polygon)(e.getSource())).getTranslateY();


            ((Polygon)(e.getSource())).toFront();

        };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> polyMoveDrag = (MouseEvent e) -> {

            double newSetX = e.getSceneX() - nwPosX;
            double newSetY = e.getSceneY() - nwPosY;
            double NSX = TX + newSetX;
            double NSY = TY + newSetY;


            ((Polygon)(e.getSource())).setTranslateX(NSX);
            ((Polygon)(e.getSource())).setTranslateY(NSY);
        };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_DRAGGED TEXT
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    EventHandler<MouseEvent> textMousePressed = (MouseEvent e) -> {

            nwPosX  = e.getSceneX();
            nwPosY  = e.getSceneY();
            TX  = ((TextField)(e.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            TY  = ((TextField)(e.getSource())).getTranslateY();


            ((TextField)(e.getSource())).toFront();

        };


    EventHandler<MouseEvent> textMoveDrag = (MouseEvent e) -> {

            double newSetX = e.getSceneX() - nwPosX;
            double newSetY = e.getSceneY() - nwPosY;
            double NSX = TX + newSetX;
            double NSY = TY + newSetY;


            ((TextField)(e.getSource())).setTranslateX(NSX);
            ((TextField)(e.getSource())).setTranslateY(NSY);
        };    


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// POPOVER PANELS FOR SIDE INFORMATION ON THE RIGHT
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     String linjetype = "Straight line";
     String rectangle = "Rectangle";
     String circle = "Circle";
     String poly1 = "Polygon";
     String text1 = "TEXT";


     Label line1 = new Label("\n"+linjetype+" ");
     Label rect1 = new Label("\n"+rectangle+" ");
     Label circ1 = new Label("\n"+circle+" ");
     Label poly2 = new Label("\n"+poly1+" ");
     Label text2 = new Label("\n"+text1+" ");

     VBox vBox = new VBox(line1);
     VBox vBox2 = new VBox(rect1);
     VBox vBox3 = new VBox(circ1);
     VBox vBox4 = new VBox(poly2);
     VBox vBox5 = new VBox(text2);

     PopOver popOver = new PopOver(vBox);
     PopOver popOver2 = new PopOver(vBox2);
     PopOver popOver3 = new PopOver(vBox3);
     PopOver popOver4 = new PopOver(vBox4);
     PopOver popOver5 = new PopOver(vBox5);


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EVENTHANDLER: MOUSE_PRESSED LINE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e-> {
            if(linebtn.isSelected()) {
            popOver.show(pane);
            line = new Line();
            line.setStartX(e.getX());
            line.setStartY(e.getY());  
            line.setStroke(cpFill.getValue()); 
            line.setOnMousePressed(lineMousePressed);
            line.setOnMouseDragged(lineMoveDrag);
            pane.getChildren().add(line);  
            }



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_PRESSED RECTANGLE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            else if(rectbtn.isSelected()) {
            popOver2.show(pane);
            rect = new Rectangle(); 
            rect.setX(e.getX());                
            rect.setY(e.getY());     
            rect.setStroke(cpLine.getValue());
            rect.setFill(cpFill.getValue());  
            rect.setOnMousePressed(rectMousePressed);
            rect.setOnMouseDragged(rectMoveDrag);
            pane.getChildren().add(rect);
            }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_PRESSED CIRCLE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            else if(circbtn.isSelected()) {
            popOver3.show(pane);
            circ = new Circle();
            circ.setStroke(cpLine.getValue());
            circ.setFill(cpFill.getValue());
            circ.setCenterY(e.getY());
            circ.setCenterX(e.getX());
            pane.getChildren().add(circ);
            circ.setOnMousePressed(circlMousePressed);
            circ.setOnMouseDragged(circMoveDrag);
            }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_PRESSED POLYGON
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            else if(polybtn.isSelected()) {
            popOver4.show(pane);
            poly = new Polygon();
            x[count] = e.getX();
            y[count] = e.getY(); 
            poly.setStroke(cpLine.getValue());
            poly.setFill(cpFill.getValue());
            poly.setOnMousePressed(polyMousePressed);
            poly.setOnMouseDragged(polyMoveDrag);
            pane.getChildren().add(poly);
            } 


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_PRESSED TEXTFIELD
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            else if(textbtn.isSelected()){
            popOver5.show(pane);
            text = new TextField();
            text.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 30));    
            text.setOnMousePressed(textMousePressed);
            text.setOnMouseDragged(textMoveDrag);
            text.toFront();
            pane.getChildren().add(text);
            }

         }); 


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EVENTHANDLER: MOUSE_RELEASED RECTANGLE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e-> {
            if(rectbtn.isSelected()) {
            rect.setWidth(e.getX() - rect.getX());
            rect.setHeight(e.getY() - rect.getY());
            }     

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_RELEASED LINE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            else if(linebtn.isSelected()) {
            line.setEndX(e.getX());
            line.setEndY(e.getY());

            }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_RELEASED CIRCLE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            else if(circbtn.isSelected()) {
            //Math.abs gives exact value of the radius
            circ.setRadius(Math.abs(e.getX() - circ.getCenterX()) + Math.abs(e.getY() - circ.getCenterY()) / 2);
             }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MOUSE_RELEASED POLYGON
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           else if(polybtn.isSelected()) {
            values.add(x[count]);
            values.add(y[count]);
            count++;
            poly.getPoints().addAll(values);
           }
      });

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// STAGE AND SCENE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        BorderPane pane1 = new BorderPane();
        pane1.setTop(buttons);
        pane1.setRight(colors);
        pane1.setCenter(pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane1, 800, 450);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tegneprogram");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }  
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// END
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So in my mind I was thinking that the Figure superclass would be something like this, you have all the object instances in here plus the colors of the shapes and so on:

```
public class Figur {

     Rectangle rect; 
     Line line;
     Polygon poly;
     Circle circ;
     TextField text;

     ColorPicker cpFill;
     ColorPicker cpLine;

}
```

And then maybe set all eventhandlers for drawing the figures in separate subclasses. Is that possible, and how would I go about connecting this together?

The Line subclass could be something likes this, with a "createdLine" method that draws the line. And the same goes for the other shapes to.

```
public class Line extends Figur {

    public void createLine(){

            popOver.show(pane);
            super(line);
            line.setStartX(e.getX());
            line.setStartY(e.getY());  
            line.setStroke(cpFill.getValue()); 
            line.setOnMousePressed(lineMousePressed);
            line.setOnMouseDragged(lineMoveDrag);
            pane.getChildren().add(line);  
         }
    }
```

And the drawing method for ending the line:

```
public void endLine(){
        line.setEndX(e.getX());
        line.setEndY(e.getY());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to declare `Figur` (I'm assuming this misspelled version is what you want) as an abstract class with only these members: `cpFill`, `cpLine`, `mousePressedHandler`, `mouseDraggedHandler` and a constructor which receives arguments for `cpFill` and `cpLine`. Then for each subclass you need to declare which shape object in contains and a constructor which defines `mousePressedHandler` and `mouseDraggedHandler`.

Edit: Code samples to better demonstrate what I described above

```
public abstract class Figure {
    private ColorPicker cpFill;
    private ColorPicker cpLine;
    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousePressedHandler;
    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseDraggedHandler;

    public Figur(ColorPicker cpFill, ColorPicker cpLine) {
        this.cpFill = cpFill;
        this.cpLine = cpLine;
    }
}

public class MyRectangle extends Figure {
    private Rectangle rect;

    public MyRectangle(ColorPicker cpFill, ColorPicker cpLine) {
        super(cpFill, cpLine);

        mousePressedHandler = e -> {
            // do something with your rectangle here
        }

        mouseDraggedHandler = e -> {
            // do another thing with your rectangle here
        }

        rect.setOnMousePressed(mousePressedHandler);
        rect.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDraggedHandler);
    }
}

public class MyLine extends Figure {
    private Line line;

    public MyRectangle(ColorPicker cpFill, ColorPicker cpLine) {
        super(cpFill, cpLine);

        mousePressedHandler = e -> {
            // do something with your line here
        }

        mouseDraggedHandler = e -> {
            // do another thing with your line here
        }

        line.setOnMousePressed(mousePressedHandler);
        line.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDraggedHandler);
    }
}
```

Note: now that I've written the code, I realised you don't event need to declare `mousePressedHandler` and `mouseDraggedHandler` in your abstract class. However, I still leave them there to keep things a bit more clear. Feel free to remove them and just call

```
line.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    // something
});

line.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
    // another thing
});
```

instead

Comment: So if I only have  cpFill, cpLine, mousePressedHandler mouseDraggedHandler in the abstract class you also need the object instances to make the code work right? So should I or should I not have these in the abstract class ?

     Rectangle rect; 
     Line line;
     Polygon poly;
     Circle circ;
     TextField text;

Comment: You shouldn't because those are specific to the subclasses. I explained in my answer that you should declare one of those for each of your subclasses

Comment: I'm a total noob at this stuff btw, so thanks for helping out. When it comes to the mousePressedHandler and mouseDraggedHandler, do I just set up the usual structure from what I have in the main? I don't really get it... :/ I've made a constructor that receives cpFill and cpLine now.

public Figure(ColorPicker cpFill, ColorPicker cpLine) {
    this.cpFill = cpFill;
    this.cpLine = cpLine;
    
}

Comment: So, I've now written all the subclasses! :D I have some trouble with some of the methods in them though, they come up red. Is it any way to import those? :) For instance, "setEndX" method in the line subclass, MOUSE_RELEASED eventhandler is marked in red.

Comment: `setEndX` is a method of `Line`, so you should write `line.setEndX`; as for `MOUSE_RELEASED`, you need to write `MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED`

Comment: So my code for MOUSE_RELEASED looks like this now. 

    MOUSE_RELEASED = e -> {
    line.setEndX(e.getX());
    line.setEndY(e.getY());
        
    };

"line.setEndX" is as you see already applied (but still red). I tried to import the circle class but that doesn't work. If I do this: 

   EventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED e -> {
    line.setEndX(e.getX());
    line.setEndY(e.getY());
        
    };

the red markings on the setEnd methods disappear but "EventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED e -> " is all red, probably because it's already defined in the Figure class.

Comment: The problem is with your syntax which looks very wrong (this part `EventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED e`). It shouldn't take long to google the correct syntax (I believe the code I provided also has correct syntax). Also you can usually tell why it's wrong by hovering on that part in the IDE, it might also suggest fixes if possible.